# How to correct JPEG files

Tags: windows-7

I lost data from memory card. I download a recovery software. This software recovered all files but the problem is that some of the images that are recovered are unable to open or some of them get blurred. Any one help me to correct this

Comment: More information is needed about the files that cannot be opened; it is doubtful that a memory card error caused other files to be blurred.

Comment: I was thinking the "blur" that is being referred to is a "progressive" jpeg. If only the first few sectors of a Progressive jpegs data  was recovered, it might still contain the data for the limited quick view, and not the whole full res full bit jpeg data that follows?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably out of luck - most likely the software you used to recover the files looked at the raw disk and took whatever it could - what you are seeing is corruption where either it could not get back everything - maybe because some of it had been overwritten, maybe because of fragmentation on the disk.

Without knowing what software recovery program you used, it is difficult to advise if there is any prospect of other software doing a better job, or indeed if it is still possible for other software to be used.   (Similarly you should advise how you lost data on the memory card, and what kind of data was on the card - was it a camera with only images ?)